# Equivalent temperature: laser and cell containing Rb

Tags: optics, terminology, laser, spectroscopy

What's the meaning of "equivalent temperature" related to a cell containing rubidium and crossed by laser?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider providing a reference for the statement.

Comment: Please give us a little more background.  Where did you find the term; was it in a paper?  What is the experiment; are you pumping the Rubidium with the laser?

Comment: A professor asked us to find it but he refused to give any other hint. I'm pumping Rubidium with laser. I can't find nothing about the definition of "eq. temperature". @ChrisMueller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring any other information, I'll tell you what I think equivalent temperature means in this case.

In a laser gain medium (such as Rubidium) the atoms are put into a non-equilibrium excited state referred to as a [population inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion).  In an equilibrium treatment of thermodynamics it is impossible for a system to reach such a state because even at infinite temperature the number of atoms in the excited and ground states would be equal.  Hence, the 'equivalent temperature' associated with a population of atoms in such a state is actually [negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_absolute_temperature).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... but how can I find the value?

Comment: The internet is very powerful my friend.  I've given you the pieces; now you have to complete the puzzle. Good luck!